# How do I disable MaxAllowedPing on my Conan Exiles dedicated server?

Tags: hosting, server-administration, conan-exiles

The server host I use sometimes has issues with the query port, causing the ping to show as 9999 until the issue is cleared. In an effort to improve the experience for my users, I want to entirely disable the MaxAllowedPing functionality, however, I cannot find any information anywhere on how to do that, only that it can be done (as stated [in their official post here](https://steamcommunity.com/games/440900/announcements/detail/2641773114877840704)

> Some of our servers will have the MaxPingAllowed filter removed and made region free so there are still servers available for everyone around the globe to play on.

As a workaround, I have set the value to 99999, but I'd prefer to disable it entirely.